# without an extra "printf" my code give me segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a C program in Linux.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(int *r)
{
    *r=20;

     r--;
    *r=30;

     r--;
    *r=40;
}

int main()
{
    int a=2;
    int b=3;
    int c=4;

    fun(&c);

    printf("a=%d\nb=%d\nc=%d",a,b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code it gives me a segmentation fault (core dumped).

But when I print the addresses of `a`, `b`, and `c` in the main function before the function call the code works.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(int *r)
{*r=20;

r--;

*r=30;
r--;

*r=40;
}
int main()
{

int a=2;
int b=3;
int c=4;

printf("a=%p\nb=%p\nc=%p\n",&a,&b,&c);

fun(&c);


printf("a=%d\nb=%d\nc=%d",a,b,c);

return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this happened?

Comment: Please metion the print statement which you used to print adresses.

Comment: You can't declare three independent scalar variables and then use pointer addition/subtraction to jump between them like this.  C does not make any guarantees about allocation order.  You need to declare them as an array, e.g. `int a[3];` if you want to do pointer arithmetic like this.

Comment: I cannot easily read the code anyway, so It gets down and close-voted for formatting.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `c` is a *single* variable, and you pass the address of this variable to `fun()`. Later, inside `fun()` you try to move the pointer and then dereference it. It actually invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Only the array elements are guaranteed to be allocated contiguous memory locations, separate variables can very well be allocated in compiler-dependent way.

You can define an array like

```
 int a[3] = {0};
```

and then, call `fun()` like

```
 fun(&a[2]);
```

and get the desired result in a well-defined way.

Comment: Exactly. Not only we are not sure a,b and c are put in the stack in this order, but also we cannot even know if b and c are in the stack as their addresses (`&b` and `&c`) are never used and thus, compiler could very well decide they are volatile.

Answer (score 2):

It may have something to do with whatever optimizations your compiler applies (or doesn't). This certainly is not portable code. If it works at all, that is by luck only, as C makes no guarantees about the order in which variables are allocated. This program seems to depend on undefined behavior.